# How to add to static table in Xamarin iOS(Monotouch)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to add cells to a static table that I created using storyboard. I want to be able to add cell to one section of it dynamically from code, I implemented a custom UITableViewSource but it keeps overwriting my static cells. How should I implement GetCell() method so it will work with static cells too? Looks like in ObjectiveC it can be done by following:

`return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]`

But how to implement it in Xamarin iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using this code:

```
    public partial class StaticTableController : UITableViewController
    {
        public StaticTableController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        [Export("tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var selector = new Selector("tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:");

            //WTF?
            var cell = new UITableViewCell(Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr(SuperHandle, selector.Handle, tableView.Handle, indexPath.Handle));
            if (indexPath.Row == 2)
            {
                cell.TextLabel.Text = "Dynamic thingy";
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

Looks a bit weird, you might be better off using a dynamic table instead. One thing I tried that doesn't work is modifying the number of cells in a section -- this just seems to directly crash with the Obj-C version of an "index out of range" inside `UITableView`.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a similar thing as you described here. The only difference is my table is completely static and I wish to access it's cells in the GetCell function but it never gets called. I tried to implement it as you explained in your answer, by adding the Export attribute, but it makes no difference. How do I go about it?